# Python 3 TypeError: utf_8_encode() must be str not bytes using Requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to get the contents of a .txt page that requires a login and password to access. I get a TypeError when trying to pass through the page and print its contents:

```
TypeError: utf_8_encode() argument 1 must be str, not bytes
```

My code for accessing this data is:

```
import requests
with requests.Session() as c:
        url = 'https://www.naturalgasintel.com/user/login'
        data_url = 'https://naturalgasintel.com/ext/resources/Data-Feed/Daily-GPI/'
        username = 'manguy'
        password = 'hi123'
        c.get(url)
        login_data = dict(username=username, password=password)
        c.post(url, data=login_data, headers={'Referer':'https://www.naturalgasintel.com/'})
        page = c.get('https://naturalgasintel.com/ext/resources/Data-Feed/Daily-GPI/2018/10/20181009td.txt')
        print(page.content)
```

First I access the parent url to log in then use the data url to grab the contents I want.

I need to translate some old Python 2.0 module commands (Twill) to Python 3.0 
commands using Requests module. Specifically I need to translate the lines:

```
data = get_browser().result.get_page()
datafile = open(localfile, "w", encoding="utf-8")
datafile.write(data)
datafile.close()
```

Where `page` in my script is basically equivalent to `data` in the original so I can write contents to a file.

Is there an easy way to translate this? Would I need to somehow translate the bytes to strings somehow?

Comment: I get no such error with  3.6.5

Comment: I did not get this error. I checked `request/urllib3` but `utf8_encode` does not exist. Can you provide more details about your traceback.

Answer (score 0):

the error come from file writing, you can either use

```
datafile = open(localfile, "wb")
datafile.write(page.content)
datafile.close()
```

Or

```
datafile = open(localfile, "w", encoding="utf-8")
datafile.write(page.text)
datafile.close()
```